# Play + Play2War

Tags: playframework

All.

I use a play framevork project.
I want run my project on tomcat server
I have problem create war file use Play2War.
Use Play 2.4.2 version.

**plugins.sbt**

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % Option(System.getProperty("play.version")).getOrElse("2.4.0"))

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" %% "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")

resolvers += "Play2war plugins release" at "http://repository-play-war.forge.cloudbees.com/release/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.4-beta1")

// TODO: find a way to automatically load sbt plugins of projects we depend on // if you see this and know how to do it, please open a pull request :)

// Uncomment the next line for local development of the Play Authentication core: //addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "sbt-pgp" % "1.0.0")

// Uncomment the next line for local development of the Play Authentication core: //addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "0.8.5")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")
```

**build.sbt**

```
import com.github.play2war.plugin._

organization := "myhome"

name := "myapp"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += "Play2war plugins release" at "http://repository-play-war.forge.cloudbees.com/release/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.4-beta1")

Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings

// Servlet version compatible with Tomcat 7
// See https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin#server-compatibility
Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "3.0"

val appDependencies = Seq(
  "be.objectify"  %% "deadbolt-java"     % "2.4.0",
  // Comment the next line for local development of the Play Authentication core:
  "com.feth"      %% "play-authenticate" % "0.7.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.postgresql"    %  "postgresql"        % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJdbc,
  "org.abstractmeta" % "compilation-toolbox" % "0.3.3",
  "org.reflections" % "reflections" % "0.9.9-RC1",
  "org.beanshell" % "bsh" % "2.0b5",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.4",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.5" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
  "org.easytesting" % "fest-assert" % "1.4" % "test"
)

// add resolver for deadbolt an     d easymail snapshots
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

//  Uncomment the next line for local development of the Play Authenticate core:
//lazy val playAuthenticate = project.in(file("modules/play-authenticate")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
  )
  /* Uncomment the next lines for local development of the Play Authenticate core: */
  //.dependsOn(playAuthenticate)
  //.aggregate(playAuthenticate)

includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"

// for minified *.min.css files
LessKeys.compress := true


fork in run := true
```

**error:**

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.play2war#play2-war-plugin;1.4-beta1: not found
[error] Total time: 12 s, completed 07.08.2015 1:33:14
```

what am I doing wrong?
*Help me, please*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are mixing things up.

Keep all instances of `addSbtPlugin(...)` inside plugins.sbt and all instances of `resolvers += ...` on build.sbt. Also try to put organize them together and see how that goes.